# Decimal fraction conversion to binary - how to convert 0.1?

Tags: binary

I am curious about transfor the decimal fraction 0.1 into binary.

I know a method to do this if I have other decimal fractions - for instance 0.75

1) 0.75 * 2 = 1.5     >= 1 - then it becomes 1

2) 0.5  * 2 = 1       >= 1 - then it becomes 1

The result in binary: 0,11

But if the decimal fraction is 0.1 - how to apply this method?

1) 0.1 * 2 = 0 < 1 then it becomes 0

It becomes 0 and nothing else

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert a fraction to binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987176/how-do-you-convert-a-fraction-to-binary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
0.1 * 2 = 0.2 --> 0 with remainder 0.2
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 --> 0 with remainder 0.4
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 --> 0 with remainder 0.8
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 --> 1 with remainder 0.6
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 --> 1 with remainder 0.2
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 --> 0 with remainder 0.4
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 --> 0 with remainder 0.8
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 --> 1 with remainder 0.6
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 --> 1 with remainder 0.2
```

etc..

Now we take the results, and put a decimal point before them:

```
0.0001100110011.......
```

and so on ad infinitum.