# how to convert a fraction like (2/3, or 5/7) to binary?

Tags: binary

I know how to convert a fraction like (1/4, or 1/8) to binary number because this fraction can also be represented by 0.25, 0.125, but I'm confused about how to convert fraction like 5/7.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert a fraction to binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987176/how-do-you-convert-a-fraction-to-binary)

Comment: 'Binary' is a bit broad, and there are many ways to represent a number. However, computers in general are not very good with fractions like `5.7`. In most cases, such a value will just be rounded and stored as a [float (= floating point number)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: @MaciejLach i think it's kinda different because we can write 1/10 as 0.1, but we cannot write 5/7 with 0.xxxx because there are infinity digits.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thank you, but I still want to know how to convert 5/7 into a binary number.

Comment: 0.1 doesn't have a finite representation in binary. This is just an approximation. [Check this article](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) for detailed explanation.

Comment: @MaciejLach  Yes, I know, but 5/7 cannot be represent by a number with a decimal point....

Comment: @MaciejLach  Oh, maybe we don't need to convert the fraction to a number with decimal point in the first place.

Comment: @MaciejLach Thank you! I got it.