# How to convert decimal(with float point) to binary in Swift 3? (self written code without third-party library and Foundation)

Tags: swift3, binary, floating-point, decimal

I am looking for a simple way to convert a decimal with floating point to binary with floating point in Swift 3. For example, this code converts decimal to binary without any problems.

```
func convertToBinary(decimal: Int) -> String {

    var n = 0, c = 0, k: [String] = [], fs: String = ""

    n = decimal

    while n > 0 {

        c = n % 2
        n = n / 2
        k.append("\(c)")

    }

    for i in k.reversed() {

        fs += "\(i)"

    }

    return fs


}
```

Unfortunately, if I'm changing decimal to float it shows error message
"Cannot assign value of type 'Float' to type 'Int'"

```
c = n % 2
```

If I'm changing variable c to float it shows another error message
"'%' is unavailable: Use truncatingRemainder instead"

Okay, then I changed '%' with:

```
c = n.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2)
```

And everything worked. Unfortunately program divides the decimal number infinitely(example):

```
0.0
0.0
1.0
0.5
0.25
1.125
1.5625
0.78125
0.390625
0.195312
0.0976562
0.0488281
0.0244141
0.012207
0.00610352
0.00305176
0.00152588
0.000762939
0.00038147
0.000190735
```

and etc.

After decimal to binary conversion:

```
1.4013e-452.8026e-454.2039e-458.40779e-451.68156e-443.50325e-447.00649e-441.4013e-432.8026e-435.60519e-431.12104e-422.24208e-424.48416e-428.96831e-421.79366e-413.58732e-417.17465e-411.43493e-402.86986e-405.73972e-401.14794e-392.29589e-394.59177e-399.18355e-391.83671e-383.67342e-387.34684e-381.46937e-372.93874e-375
```

and etc.

Maybe there's some kind of workaround?

Comment: How is this related to C? How is C relevant if you're programming in Swift?

Comment: "(self written code without third-party library and Foundation)" ...? If the standard library already does what you need... why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: Are you trying to represent fractional values in binary? The above algorithm cannot capture that. I'd suggest you google "binary fractions". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987217/1271826 for a simple algorithm. Or see http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/. Or see http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm. Note, when you do this, be aware that some decimal values cannot be represented in a finite binary representation, so you might want to cap it at a certain number of digits.

Comment: Or are you trying to understand what the underlying binary representation of a floating point number looks like? That's a completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this : `func convertToBinary( dataName : dataType )`

> *Unfortunately, if I'm changing decimal to float it shows error message : 
> `"Cannot assign value of type 'Float' to type 'Int'"`*

Look at your code..

```
func convertToBinary(decimal: Int) -> String {
```

The function parameter's **data type** must be changed to match the provided input's data type.

```
func convertToBinary(decimal: Float) -> String {

//your float (fraction) processing  code

}
```

When calling the function, if you want to input parameters of either `Int` or `Float` type, you could try using wildcard `*` to accept any input. See pseudo-code example...

```
func convertToBinary(decimal: *) -> String {

//your Integer or Float processing  code
//consider using IF condition...
//#  if ( decimal.type == Int ) { ..do Integer stuff here.. }
//#  else if ( decimal.type == Float ) { ..do Float stuff here.. }

}
```

Comment: @DanielDluzhnevsky any progress? Did this solve your problem?