# Convert fraction with numerator and denominator to binary

Tags: python, binary

Have been looking for help for a couple of days but I don't think there are any answers to my question. I am sure it's basic but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I am trying to create a function to turn a fraction into binary representation. I have based it off this work here:
[How do you convert a fraction to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987217/10549008)

```
def fraction_to_binary(p,q):
    binlist = []
    n = 1
    while p >0:
        binlist.append(p*2//q)
        if p*2//q == 0:
            p *=2
            n +=1
        else:
            p = p - (p*2//q)*2**n
            n +=1
    return binlist
```

For my example I am trying to convert 11/64 to binary. My result:

```
fraction_to_binary(11,64)
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

The actual answer is `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]`, so I think I am close.

Comment: So `q` is necessarily a power of 2? And `p < q `?

Comment: @Julien yeh sorry should have verified, so p/q < 1 and I also read that any x ∈ (0, 1) can be written in the form x = ![formula][1] Xn*2^(-n-1), where (Xn ∈ {0,1})
[1]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csum_%7B0%7D%5E%7Binf%7D

Comment: Well you obviously can't output an infinite series of decimals... so you need to assume `q` is a power of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mis-translated Step 3 in your `else` case: just use `p = p*2 - q`.